# Convert unity to autofac

Tags: c#, unity-container, autofac

I am trying to convert an example piece of code I found on caching with a repository. The only problem is it's using unity for its DI and I don't have any understanding how it works.

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    IRepository<Blog> BlogRepository { get; }
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync();
}

public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private IDataStoreContext dataStoreContext;

    private readonly IUnityContainer container;

    public IRepository<Blog> BlogRepository
    {
        get
        {
            // TODO : Use unity containers to generate the UnitOfwork so that to make surethat
            // datacontext is a single instance in that instance of uow
            return new GenericRepository<Blog>(
                this.container.Resolve<ICacheStrategy<Blog>>(),
                new SqlDataStoreStrategy<Blog>(this.dataStoreContext));
        }
    }


    public UnitOfWork(IDataStoreContext dataStoreContext, IUnityContainer container)
    {
        this.dataStoreContext = dataStoreContext;
        this.container = container;
    }

    public async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        return await this.dataStoreContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.dataStoreContext.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how I should write this as an autofac statement?

I have only really ever need to use basic autofac e.g.

```
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // Create the container and use the default application services as a fallback
        AutofacRegistration.Populate(builder, services);

        builder.Register(c => new Logger())
             .As<ILogger>()
             .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Comment: What is `AutofacRegistration.Populate(builder, services);` ? how does it work ?

Comment: Your usage of Unity looks a little shaky too.  If you are passing around the container to resolve items you have done something wrong!!  I suggest cleaning up your unity usage first and then Autofac replacement will become easier.

Comment: I think what @Ruskin is getting at is that when doing dependency injection, you really should only inject what you need... If you need an IUnitOfWork, don't ask for IUnityContainer and then use that to get IUnitOfWork.... just inject the IUnitOfWork -- it will save you when doing unit testing with mocks, and generally lead to more maintainable code.